# GLTF display texture in python

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I want to receive video from other software to process and send video in python. I use glfw to display it, but the display is static.

```
if not glfw.init():
        return
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, True)
    self.window = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "Opengl GLFW Window", None, None)

    if not self.window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    glfw.make_context_current(self.window)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
```

When I only fill the color(`glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)`), the processed video can be received in other software.

```
while not glfw.window_should_close(self.window):

        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        self.aspect = self.receiveWidth / self.receiveHeight
        self.displayHeight = self.windowWidth / self.aspect
        self.padding = (self.windowHeight - self.displayHeight) / 2

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )
        glLoadIdentity()
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        glTexCoord(0, 0)        
        glVertex2f(0, self.padding)

        glTexCoord(1, 0)
        glVertex2f(self.windowWidth, self.padding)

        glTexCoord(1, 1)
        glVertex2f(self.windowWidth, self.displayHeight + self.padding)

        glTexCoord(0, 1)
        glVertex2f(0, self.displayHeight + self.padding)

        glEnd()

        glfw.swap_buffers(self.window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    glfw.destroy_window(self.window)
    glfw.terminate()
```